# Trouble trying to run code comprised of many files

Tags: julia

I recently began a project that consists of running simulations of cells. I am very new to programming and completely new to julia. I have to run this [code](https://github.com/dankolbman/BCIM) written in julia. I downloaded the language in the juno bundle found [here](http://julialang.org/downloads/). I am running windows 8.1. I had previously installed the python anaconda bundle, and later installed python 3.5 because I read that it julia compiled in 3+ versions of python.

The problem is that when I attempt to use the code (use the evaluate or evaluate all commands), none of the files I run make the program do what it is supposed to. Often something is not defined, which I can sometimes fix if I run the files that define whatever wasn't defined, but I also get a bounds error (running the cell test file) and assorted other errors. I know that the code does work if run properly.

My question is: am I handling the code wrong and if so how should I run it, or is there something else going on that I am missing?

Comment: have you read those [docs](http://bcim.readthedocs.org/index.html) yet? I think this kind of questions should be asked [here](https://github.com/dankolbman/BCIM/issues) :)

Comment: The README of the link you provide explicitly states that you need the nightly version (presumably 0.4), yet the Juno bundle only includes the release version (0.3)